# How can you get the number of the processes where program is started?

Tags: command-line, process

First of all I save in a file all of the working processes.

```
ps -el > file1
```

My idea is to count the number of lines in file1 where vi is present.

I tried something like `wc -l | grep vi file1`

How is the proper way to do it ?

Comment: Could you please explain if you're looking for all VI processes (VI the text editor) or processes containing vi, to match not only vi or vim but services as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code nearly works, you just have to change

```
wc -l | grep vi file1
```

to

```
grep vi file1 | wc -l
```

The pipe operator uses the output of the program on the left as input for the program on the right.

Comment: only grepping for vi will match all serVIces...

Answer (score 0):

Why not using `pgrep`:

```
pgrep "^vi" | wc -l
```

pgrep man page:

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>    pgrep [options] pattern
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>    pgrep looks through the currently running processes and lists the process 
>    IDs which matches the selection criteria to stdout.
> ```

**EDIT**: (Using the file):

```
ps aux > file1
awk '{ print $11 }' file1 | egrep '^vi' | wc -l
```

Comment: Thank you, but do you know how can I do it with the file?

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: @SylvainPineau i think op want to display the lines where `vi` is presented at any position.

Comment: Humm, in that case to match all "vi" patterns, remove the "^" before "^vi" so that you'll match not only vi, vim but  also services like indicator-session-service, unity-webapps-service.